# what exactly happen when transaction commit but database crash

Tags: database, transactions

A client sends a transaction to database like this:

```
begin transaction
sql1
sql2
sql3
...
end transaction (commit)
```

From my point of view, the database will follow the steps below:

- Step1: receive commands one by one
- Step2: execute commands one by one in memory
- Step3: save result from memory into disk (redo log)
- Step4: add commit flag in log when receive commit command
- Step5: response success ack to client

My questions:

- Is the description above right and accurate?
- If it's right and accurate, what will happen when that database crashes between step4 and step5? In this situation, transaction commits successly but client receives no commit success ack. So client can't tell whether transaction commits successly.

Comment: Not sure much can be done about situations such as these. Take the case of a client crash right before it displays a success message to the user, while the transaction has succeeded and an ack was sent by the server and received by the client? You would need some type of log client side. Say you retrieve money from an ATM and all is well, bank account updated but things go south and the ATM machine crashes. You clearly need a log ATM side to undo the transaction upon waking up.

Comment: This is a form of the [Two Generals Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_Generals%27_Problem).

Comment: The only thing that transactions ensure is that all the queries are committed or rolled back, it can't ensure that the success/failure message will be received by the client.

Comment: Pragmatically, there does come a time when you dearly hope that you will not be felled by a bolt out of the blue at precisely the wrong time ... and to recognize that "by now, computer hardware is pretty good."

Comment: @Barmar Nice answer. It seems that the commit problem is a coordination problem between two nodes (client and database). So is it a special case of CAP theorem or concensus problem?

Comment: @gaoxinge I think it's the concensus problem, CAP is different.